# What are graha and Nakshatras?

Tags: astrology, name

What are graha and Nakshatras?

Is there any story how they are created?

What are their effects to human?

How many graha and Nakshatras are there?

Is there a specific God for each of them? What are those names of God

Comment: [This post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21754/whats-difference-between-graha-and-loka) can help you a little.

Comment: What are their effects on humans? **None.** Only moon which causes tides on Earth has been shown to have some affect. But again it's limited to tides. Does not affect humans and their personal lives in anyway. Pluto, Neptune and Uranus are not even accounted for in Hindu jyotisha. Clearly it's outdated. Rahu-Ketu are not even planets - they are imaginary points in space.

Comment: Is Shani not effecting people?

Comment: @KailashChandraPolai Shani will defintely cause you bad effects if he is malefic in your kundali. But don't blame Shani for it, it's karma (of previous births) that is showing through Shani. In Hinduism, even Yama, God of death, is God or Deva.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 9 Grahas and 27 Nakshatras.

From [Matsya Purana](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/matsya/bookview.php?chapnum=12) the Navagrahas are:

> Adithyaya Somaaya Mangalaaya Budhaayacha
>  Guru Shukra Sanirbhyascha
>   Rahavey Ketavey Namah ||
>
> Prostrations to the nine planetary deities- Surya, Chandra, Mangala, Budha, Brihaspati, Shukra, Shani, Rahu and
>   Ketu.

They are all Devatas (Gods). Description of Surya and Moon, for example, are as follows:

> Padmaasanah Padmakarah Padmagarbha samuddhitah,
>  Saptaashvah
>   Saptarujjuscha Dwibhujah syaat sadaa Ravih ||
>
> Surya Deva has two hands wearing two lotuses, seated on a lotus
>   flower; his luster is abundant like that of the outside part of a
>   lotus; Surya Deva is comfortably seated on a magnificent chariot
>   driven by Seven Horses.
>
> Swetah Swetaambaradharah Swetaashvah Swetavaahanah
>   Gadaapaanirdwibaahus cha Kartavyo varadah Shashee ||
>
> Chandra Deva is of white colour, wears white clothes, has white
>   horses, white chariot, with gada/ mace and Varada Mudra or sign of
>   Protection.

Although, Rahu and Ketu were Asuras (demons), but they were later incorporated into the 9 Graha Devatas and are worshiped together with the other 7 as Navagrahas.

The Nakshtras are 27 in number as said earlier. From Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra's 3rd Chapter:

> 1. Maitreya: “O Maharishi, you have affectionately explained about the incarnations of Grahas. Now kindly detail their characters and
>      dispositions. 2-3. Parasar: “O Brahmin, listen to the account of
>      placement of the heavenly bodies. Out of the many luminous bodies
>      sighted in the skies some are stars, yet some are Grahas. Those, that
>      have no movements, are the Nakshatras (asterisms). 4-6. Those are
>      called ‘Grahas’, that move through the Nakshatras (or stellar
>      mansions) in the zodiac. The said zodiac comprises of 27 Nakshatras
>      commencing from Ashvini. The same area is divided in 12 parts equal to
>      12 ‘Rashis’ commencing from Mesh. The names of the Grahas commence
>      from Surya. The Rashi rising is known, as ‘Lagn’. Based on Lagn and
>      the Grahas, joining and departing from each other, the native’s good
>      and bad effects are deducted. Addition from Santhanam till Sloka 7.
>      The names of the 27 Nakshatras are Ashvini, Bharani, Krittika, Rohini,
>      Mrigasira, Ardra, Punarvasu, Pushya, Aslesha, Magha, Purvaphalguni,
>      Uttaraphalguni, Hasta, Chitra, Swati, Vishaka, Anuradha, Jyeshtha,
>      Mula, Purvashadh, Uttarashadh, Shravana, Dhanishtha, Satabhisha,
>      Purvabhadra, Uttarabhadra, Revati.

.....................................

Yes, each Nakshtra is ruled by one of the Navagrahas. For example, the 1st Nakshtra (Aswini) is ruled by Ketu and the last (Revati) is ruled by Budha.

The complete [list](http://www.drikpanchang.com/tutorials/nakshatra/nakshatra.html) is as follows:

> 1. Ashvini/Aswini      अश्विनी (KetU)
> 2. Bharani     भरणी    (Shukra)
> 3. Krittika/Krithika       कृत्तिका    (Surya)
> 4. Rohini      रोहिणी      (Chandra)
> 5. Mrigashirsha        मृगशीर्ष    (Mangal)
> 6. Ardra       आर्द्रा     (Rahu)
> 7. Punarvasu       पुनर्वसु        (Brihaspati)
> 8. Pushya      पुष्य       (Shani)
> 9. Ashlesha        आश्ळेषा/आश्लेषा     (Budha)
> 10. Magha       मघा     (Again Ketu and the same order given above follows)
> 11. Purva Phalguni      पूर्व फाल्गुनी
> 12. Uttara Phalguni     उत्तर फाल्गुनी
> 13. Hasta       हस्त
> 14. Chitra      चित्रा
> 15. Swati       स्वाति
> 16. Vishakha        विशाखा
> 17. Anuradha        अनुराधा
> 18. Jyeshtha        ज्येष्ठा
> 19. Mula    मूल
> 20. Purva Ashadha   पूर्वाषाढा
> 21. Uttara Ashadha  उत्तराषाढा
> 22. Shravana    श्रवण
> 23. Dhanishtha  श्रविष्ठा/धनिष्ठा
> 24. Shatabhisha     शतभिषक्/शततारका
> 25. Purva Bhadrapada    पूर्वभाद्रपदा/पूर्वप्रोष्ठपदा
> 26. Uttara Bhadrapada   उत्तरभाद्रपदा/उत्तरप्रोष्ठपदा
> 27. Revati  रेवती

> What are their effects to human?

This is a very broad question and i am not answering it.

Answer (score 0):

#### What are the effects of grahas and nakṣatras on humans?

None, [says](https://archive.org/stream/satyarthprakashl00dayauoft#page/n369/mode/2up/search/there+is+no+visible+connection) Swami Dayananda Saraswati in his book [Satyarth Prakash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyarth_Prakash) (literally, The Light of Truth).

> Persons become rich, poor, kings, and beggars, in consequence of their deeds and works, but not from the influence of stars. Many astrologers perform the marriages of their sons or daughters according to the oracles of astrology, still those marriages become unhappy – quarrels spoil conjugal love, parties turn widows or widowers. Had the astrological conclusions been true, no such thing would have happened. Therefore the fruits of actions are true and the motion of heavenly bodies is not the cause of human pleasure or pain. **There is no visible connection between the stars in the sky and the human beings capable of doing works and living on the earth far away from them.**
>
> Human beings are the authors and the reapers of the fruits of their actions, and God makes them suffer the consequences of their actions. As you believe in the influence of stars, you should answer the question: When a man is born on a certain time whose horoscope you cast according to the positions of the polar star and other conjunctions, is there any other person born at the same time in the world? If you reply in the negative, it is false. But if you admit it, how is it that the one becomes, say, the universal emperor in the world, and the other does not? Well, if you confess that all this trickery is a shift to earn the bread of idleness, persons will readily believe it.

Swami Vivekananda also [thought](http://belurmath.org/complete_works_of_swami_vivekananda/volume_8/notes_of_class_talks_and_lectures/man_the_maker.htm) the same:

> I have seen some astrologers who predicted wonderful things; but **I have no reason to believe they predicted them only from the stars**, or anything of the sort. In many cases it is simply mind-reading. Sometimes wonderful predictions are made, but in many cases it is arrant trash.